# Android Studio IDE got Broken

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

After sudden shutdown of computer, Android became broken.

I couldn't see the toolbar where the ADV and SDK manager are, and in Tools the only options are "Tasks & Context", "Save File as Template...", "Generate JavaDoc...", "New Scratch File...", "IDE Scripting Console" and "XML Actions".
Is like if the IDE forgot everything about Android.

I decided to uninstall Android Studio checking all options ("Android SDK" and "Android User Settings" (it took a long while). After installing normaly, and downloading all packages, I Started the IDE, opened the project and it was the same, still can't find the toolbar with the Managers.

After searching, all posts said to start the IDE in the Quick Start (which shows fine) to configure the SDK, then "Configure" > "Project Defaults" > "Project Structure" and the "Android SDK" option is nowhere to be seen. I also tried "Invalidate Caches / Restart" in the file menu but its still the same.

Windows 7, Java 1.8.0_45 Android-Studio 1.2.2

How can I fix this?

[Here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsC71.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to delete the .android and the .AndroidStudio1.2 folders within your user directory. However I did this after a third uninstall, so I don't know if it'll work without uninstalling.